# Compute the Sum of geometric series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, geometric-series

Basically, I just came out of my exam and this was a question that I wasn't sure of how to solve, I'd appreciate it if someone answered this

$$\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

Comment: Try partial fractions

Comment: I will point out that this is *not* a "geometric series."  A geometric series is a series very specifically of the form $\sum\limits_{k=n}^N a\cdot r^k$ such as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}3\cdot 2^k$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*:
$$\frac1{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}$$
Now write out the terms of the summation in this form and see which fractions cancel out. This is probably the most well-known example of what is known as a *telescoping sum*.

Comment: I appreciate it, so I basically got 1/99 - 1/100, is that the correct answer then?

Comment: @UsamaGhawji Should be $1-\frac1{100}$.